# what it means: exec `ksh -c "echo /usr/bin/expectk \"$0\" -- $*"`

Tags: bash

In my company, there are a lot of maintain scripts. I found one start
like with:

```
#!/bin/sh
# the next line restarts using expectk \
exec `ksh -c "echo /usr/bin/expectk \"$0\" -- $*"`
```

But I don't understand why and how it restarts using expectk.

Anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

That command looks way more complicated than it needs to be. Essentially what its doing (and could be shortened down to) is

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/expectk $0 -- $*
```

Your script is `exec`ing the output of the echo command. The rewritten version above removes the echo and just does the exec directly.
However the better way to do it is

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/expectk "$0" -- "$@"
```

This fixes issues that would pop up if any of the arguments to the script contained spaces.